# How to order by length inside WITH clause SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, row-number

Order by Length is not working inside the WITH clause.

```
;WITH Invalids AS
(
    SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES
        GroupNumber, 
        RTRIM(Address1) Address1, 
        RTRIM(Postcode) Postcode
    FROM dbo.LoadData WHERE GroupNumber NOT IN
    (
        '000','016','018','025','044','048','049','053','054','055','060','064','067','069','071','073'
    )
    ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY GroupNumber ORDER BY LEN(Address1) DESC, LEN(Postcode) DESC )
)
UPDATE dbo.LoadData
SET 
    Valid = 0, 
    Reason = Reason + 'Bad address; '
WHERE GroupNumber = 
(
    SELECT GroupNumber FROM Invalids WHERE LEN(Address1) = 0 OR LEN(Postcode) = 0
```

Comment: It would help to understand your issue if you provided some sample data, actual output and expected output. I have tested your query and from what I can see, your `order by` statement does what it should do. Note: `len` does not count trailing blanks so this would be `0`, `select len('   ')`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`TOP... WITH TIES` is going to give you everything that has a matching value in the `ORDER BY` clause. Because your 'ORDER BY' clause is just a row number that is partitioned by GroupNumber, then every GroupNumber that has at least one record will have one of those records with a row number of 1. Therefore you will return 1 record for every GroupNumber. MSDN also says "The returned order of tying records is arbitrary. ORDER BY does not affect this rule."

I'm going to guess that your 'ORDER BY' in the CTE should simply be:

`ORDER BY GroupNumber, LEN(Address1) DESC, LEN(Postcode) DESC`

If so, then you would get the lowest GroupNumber, and the longest value for Address1, with the longest value for Postcode, and any duplicates.

On the other hand, if you **do** want the longest address and postal code for *every* GroupNumber, then you should already be getting that and I would ask for more information.